# What are the advantages and disadvantages of this algorithm used to determine if a number is prime?

Tags: c++, algorithm

Here is my code. I am primarily wanting to know how this compares to other algorithms in terms of speed and memory.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool isPrime(int input){
    for(int i = 2; i <= input; i++)
        if(input%i == 0 && i < input)
            return false;
    return true;
}

int main(){
    int input;
    cin >> input;
    cout << isPrime(input);
}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review.

Comment: No, it's not about code review.  It's asking about algorithms, not coding practices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, your algorithm takes linear time, O(n). You can speed it up tremendously if you check only the numbers up to `sqrt(n)`: (`i * i <= n`). That being said, if you want to check k numbers of size ~n for being prime, you would end up with `O(k sqrt (n))`. That's still bad.

In this case, you would built a sieve ([Atkins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Atkin) or [Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)), which can be implemented in `O(n log log n)` for numbers up to `n`. This way, every following test can be done in O(1).

Answer (score 2):

For one thing you need to be trying odd numbers and stepping by 2, because none of the even candidates (except 2) is itself prime. For another your loop needs to terminate at `i <= input / 3` for the same reason. I have increased your execution speed sixfold.

```
bool isPrime(int input){
    int endval = input / 3;
    if (input <= 2) 
       return true;
    if ((input & 1) == 0)
       return false;
    for( int i = 3; i <= endval; i+=2)
        if(input%i == 0)
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You can trivially speed yours up: Make it `if(input<4) return true:`. Not much, but...

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this (not sure if I checked all possible cases). To avoid a potential overflow issue, i <= (input/i) is used instead of (i*i) <= input.

```
bool isPrime(int input){
int i;
    if(input%2 == 0)
        return false;
    for(i = 3; i <= (input/i); i += 2)
        if(input%i == 0)
            return false;
    return true;
}
```